# R - How to extract values for the same named elements across multiple objects of the same type?

Tags: r

I have a series of objects storing the results of some statistical models in my workspace. Call them "model1", "model2", etc. Each of these models has the same set of named elements attached, $coef, for example. I would like to extract into a list or vector the values stored in a particular element from all objects containing the string "model".

The following code entered at the command line does what I want:

```
unlist(lapply(parse(text = paste0(ls()[grep("model", ls() )], "$", "coef")), eval))
```

From this, I've created the following generic function:

```
get.elements <- function(object, element) {
    unlist(lapply(parse(text = paste0(ls()[grep(object, ls() )], "$", element)), eval))
}
```

However, when I run this function I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = paste0(ls()[grep(object, ls() )], "$", element)) : 
  <text>:1:1: unexpected '$'
1: $
   ^
```

Q1. Why does this code work when run from the command line but not as a function, and more importantly, how do I fix it?

Q2. Even better, is there a simpler method that will accomplish the same thing? This seems like such a common task for statisticians and simulation modelers that I would expect some kind of command in the base package, yet I've been unable to find anything. Surely there must be a more elegant way to do this than my cumbersome method.

Thanks for all help.

--Dave

Comment: What arguments are you using to call the function?

Comment: You can access the coefficients from a model with the code `m[["coefficients"]]`, so you could just do `m[[element]]`. Also, keeping multiple models as variables named `model1`, `model2` is a poor choice: you should keep them as a list of models. That way, you can get the coefficients like this: `lapply(models, function(m) m[[element]])`

Answer (score 13):

Q1) The code fails because `ls()` looks in the environment of the function and since there are no matching objects there,

```
paste0(ls()[grep(object, ls() )], "$", element)
```

is equivalent to

```
paste0("$", element)
```

To get `ls()` to look in your workspace, you'd need `ls(pos = 1)`.

Q2) This is a common task, but as far as know there isn't a function to do this because where the models are, what they are called, what objects you want to extract and how you want them returned will depend on your requirements. A slightly neater version of what you propose above would be

```
nm <- paste0("model", 1:2) # adjust numbers as required
unlist(lapply(nm, function(x) get(nm)$coef))
```

Alternatively you could put your models in a list and use

```
modList <- list(model1, model2)
unlist(lapply(modList, "[[", "coefficients"))
```

Comment: I believe you can replace `unlist(lapply())` by a single call to `sapply`, i.e. `sapply(modList, "[[", "coefficients"))`.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra There is one problem with `sapply` in this case: If the coefficient names of the first model are not identical to the one of the second, the output (in which only the names of the first model are used) could be misleading. This, of course, is only relevant if all models have the same number of coefficients. If the number of coefficients differs, the output from `sapply` will be identical to the one of `lapply`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein point taken, I think using `unlist` is better.

Comment: Thanks! Info about environments and how ls() works inside of functions is especially helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use map from the [purrr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/purrr.pdf).

```
l1 <- list(a1 = 3, a2 = 2)
l2 <- list(a1 = 334, a2 = 34)
l3 <- list(a1 = 90, a2 = 112)

l <- list(l1, l2, l3)

purrr::map(l, "a1")
```

this gives:

```
### Result
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 334

[[3]]
[1] 90
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to obtain the desired output:

```
get.elements <- function(object, element) {
 unlist(lapply(ls(pattern = object, .GlobalEnv),
        function(x) get(x, .GlobalEnv)[[element, exact = FALSE]]))
}
```

Both `element` and `object` are character strings.

Note that I used the argument `exact = FALSE`, since the element is named `coefficients`, not `coef`. In this way, you can still use `element = "coef"`.

Comment: This seems quite cumbersome in relation to using a list and indexing that, see the answer of @HeatherTurner.

Comment: Agreed, but this will only work if the objects are already in a list.

Comment: And the OP should do that IMO, not hard to do :)

Comment: People seem to forget that `ls` has a `pattern` argument and that `grep` has a `value` argument

Comment: +1 Great ideas @GSee ! - I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing to these tricks.

Comment: If you're going to use `get` inside a function, it's best if you specify the `pos` or `envir`

Comment: Thanks for the advice about combining the models into a list object. And thanks, GSee, for pointing out that nesting grep inside of ls() is redundant.